# How to use an outer query variable in a nested sub query using update

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

I am using an update query in which I use an outer variable in a nested sub query, but I find an error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "FS"."GR_NUMBER": invalid identifier

```
update table fs set fs.branch_id=
(select branch_id
from
    (select  branch_id,row_number() over(PARTITION by gr_number order by updated_ts desc) as Sno
from admission_log
where gr_number=fs.gr_number )
where sno=1) ;
```

Comment: Is table FS has column name `GR_NUMBER`? Your query seems fine to me. Please provide the output of the `DESC FS`

Comment: yes table fs has column GR_NUMBER

Comment: i modify my question please look this error..

Comment: I have rolled this question back to its earlier version. Questions should not be modified with a new version one answers have been given, since that invalidates the existing answers. **Please ask a new question** for your new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your query is that you're trying to access the `fs.gr_number` column in a subquery that's two levels down. You can only access the top level column in a subquery one level down.

Your statement should be:

```
UPDATE fs
SET    fs.branch_id = (SELECT branch_id
                       FROM   (SELECT branch_id,
                                      gr_number,
                                      row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY gr_number ORDER BY updated_ts DESC) AS sno
                               FROM   admission_log) x
                       WHERE  x.gr_number = fs.gr_number
                       AND    sno = 1);
```

That moves the correlation to one level down. Note how I've also aliased the nested subquery.

The performance shouldn't be terrible, since the `x.gr_number = fs.gr_number` predicate involves the same column in the subquery which the analytic function is being partitioned on. That should allow Oracle to filter the subquery appropriately.

---

ETA: you could also use a MERGE statement instead:

```
MERGE INTO fs tgt
  USING (SELECT branch_id,
                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY gr_number ORDER BY updated_ts DESC) AS sno
         FROM   admission_log) src
    ON (tgt.gr_number = src.gr_number AND src.sno = 1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE tgt.branch_id = src.branch_id;
```

Comment: (I have rolled the question back, and have asked the question author to post a new question).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's Oracle, you can use a merge clause and use the min() function to get the value instead of the row_number() function.

```
merge into table fs using
(select gr_number, min(branch_id) as branch_id from admission_log) qry
on
(fx.gr_number = qry.gr_number)
when matched then
update
set
fs.branch_id = qry.branch_id;
```

If you still wanted to use the roe_number() function, below is the query. Your WHERE clause to join the table should be outside the subquery.

```
update table fs set fs.branch_id=
(select branch_id
from
(select  branch_id,row_number() over(PARTITION by gr_number order by updated_ts desc)
as Sno
from admission_log)
where sno=1
and gr_number=fs.gr_number) ;
```

Comment: `min(branch_id)` isn't necessarily going to give the right result though.

Comment: Why not, you are taking rownum = 1, here its min(branch_id). What difference does it make? Grouping  gr_number with respect to min(branch_id) will provide same result as same as taking the rownum = 1. If he wants to take something other that 1st row number, min(branch_id) dosen't make sense

Comment: The analytic function is finding the latest branch_id based on the latest updated_ts value. If the latest row's branch_id is 10, but an earlier row has 5, your `min(branch_id)` would return the wrong value.

Comment: (I have rolled the question back, and have asked the question author to post a new question).

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
update fs a
set a.branch_id =
   (select c.branch_id
      from (select b.branch_id,
                   row_number() over(PARTITION by b.gr_number order by b.updated_ts desc) as Sno
              from admission_log b
             where b.gr_number = a.gr_number) c
     where c.sno = 1);
```